Brotli (compression) is enabled BUT some of my scripts are not compressed
lighthouse and Google pagespeed insights are telling me to enable text compression.
(but it's enabled.)
But I asked my hosting server, and I checked my info.php and it's enabled.
even in chrome > inspect > network > headers > response headers > content-encoding
I can see the the word "br" which I think stands for Brotli.
I even add the below codes at the end of my .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_brotli.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

some of my script has it , some of them don't ...
why? and how should I fix this??
Thank you all.
